# F# type inferrence issue

Tags: f#

I have experienced the following problem while writing a test. Please find a  picture bellow.

[image]

If I create validateGameExistance function in the unit test project then it works fine.

How could it be solved?

Comment: Do you need the type annotation on the left side? Perhaps you shadow the types the function uses. That's about all that can be said without seeing actual code.

Comment: @scrwtp nothing is shadowed, Im explicity setting the parameters types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is hard to give a definite answer (based just on the screenshot), but you can get this kind of error when some of the types involved in the type error are defined in multiple places (so, the type name would look the same, but they would actually be different types in different assemblies).

For example, if the `Result<T>` type is defined in multiple projects and the function you're calling returns one of them, but your annotation is referring to another one.

Comment: Yes!, Chessie was referenced in many projects as a f# file. Problem solved!